# Zend framework 2 mod in the where clause

Tags: mysql, zend-framework2, zend-db

```
$select->columns(array('id','state','time'));
$select->where->lessThan('rec', $to)->and->greaterThan('rec', $from);
$select->order('rec ASC');
```

This is my sql query to get the values based on some range. The result will give me a specific set of rows. I would like to do a mod operation on this.

Like, `select * from table where rec mod 5 = 0;` which will return every 5th record instead of all the records. How can i do that here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use `Zend\Db\Sql\Predicate\Expression`

```
$select->columns(array('id','state','time'));

$modwhere = new \Zend\Db\Sql\Predicate\Expression('rec mod 5 = 0');
$select->where($modwhere);

$select->order('rec ASC');
```